# How to detect clockwise/counterclockwise mouse/cursor drag in cocoa (osx)?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm relatively new to objective-c and cocoa development, and I'm curious if there is a relatively simple way to detect clockwise or counterclockwise mouse/cursor dragging?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't sure if it is possible in cocoa. You can try to solve this problem by yourself, grabbing start point, end point and some middle point coordinates, create two vectors based on that points and find signed area of the triangle. For the math see [this document](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~rs/AlgsDS07/16Geometric.pdf) (Search for the "Implementing CCW").

Here is a simple function:

```
int ccw(CGPoint a, CGPoint b, CGPoint c)
{
    const int area2 = (b.x - a.x)*(c.y - a.y) - (b.y - a.y)*(c.x - a.x);
    if (area2 < 0) return -1; // clockwise
    if (area2 > 0) return +1; // counter-clockwise
    return 0; // collinear
}
```

**Edit**: note that your y-axis probably will point from top to bottom, so you may need to switch sign of the result or convert y coordinate of points before passing to the function.

Comment: Just tried integrating it into my code...looks like it's working! Thank you Cody!